How to call a self-signed certificate ip address using its certificate in Spring Boot?
I need to call an external url to my Spring Boot application via https.
The external url ( as IP address ) uses a self-signed certificate and made it available, I don't want to install the certificate in the jdk but I want to call it using its certificate.
This is the equivalent cURL command
curl --cacert <path_to_self_signed_cert_file> https://xxx...

